# Azure RedHat vm yum update fails with "SSL peer rejected your certificate as expired."

Tags: azure, redhat, yum

I just started a Standard RedHat 7 VM on Azure.

I login and type:

```
sudo yum update
```

and get:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos
https://rhui-3.microsoft.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7Server/x86_64/dotnet/1/debug/repodata/repomd.xml:
[Errno 14] curl#58 - "SSL peer rejected your certificate as expired."
Trying other mirror.
https://rhui-1.microsoft.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7Server/x86_64/dotnet/1/debug/repodata/repomd.xml:
[Errno 14] curl#58 - "SSL peer rejected your certificate as expired."
Trying other mirror.
...
```

I thought that the PAYG license include updates? Or is the current image broken?
Tried the 7.4 image too?

Comment: Take a look [this](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1073). Maybe it's helpful.

Comment: Also, you could run the command with root.

Comment: This is also affecting me, Azure RHEL VM and it's only started happening in the past few days. I'm going to lodge a support ticket with Microsoft.

Answer (score 36):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/redhat/redhat-rhui#update-expired-rhui-client-certificate-on-a-vm), you can run this command to update the RHUI client certificate on the Azure RedHat VM:

```
sudo yum update -y --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo='*microsoft*'
```

And now you should be able to download/update packages packages without the `SSL peer rejected your certificate as expired` error.

Tested this on **Azure RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.3** and it works fine for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is the official solution.

Comment: Confirmed this is the only needed step, in Jan 2022 on a RHEL 7.9 VM.

Answer (score 12):

I also faced same issue yesterday. I referred to following links on Redhat Support Portal.

- https://access.redhat.com/articles/3189332 (for instructions to link Azure account with RH Portal and register for portal,
- (registration must) https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3167021

Though my problem didn't got resolved from the above post after following instructions as it is, after taking cue from the problem description, following worked for me. In my case, older version of "rhui-azure-rhel7" RPM was installed on VM I had setup few weeks back where I was facing same issue as yours.

```
curl -o azureclient.rpm https://rhui-1.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/microsoft-azure-rhel7/rhui-azure-rhel7-2.2-74.noarch.rpm
rpm -U azureclient.rpm
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the correct answer. RHEL machines use client certificates to authenticate to to the Red Hat Update Infrastructure. That cert has expired and needs a manual update via the package rhui-azure-rhel7, and the exact version number gets updated over time.

Comment: Thanks! A more direct form worked for me too:

```rpm -Uvh https://rhui-1.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/microsoft-azure-rhel7/rhui-azure-rhel7-2.2-74.noarch.rpm```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue previously and the workaround provided by Azure support was to run the following commands:

```
wget  https://rhui-1.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/microsoft-azure-rhel7/rhui-azure-rhel7-2.2-74.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -U rhui-azure-rhel7-2.2-74.noarch.rpm
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum repolist
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to update the RHUI certificate using the Microsoft-provided RPM.

RHEL 6:

```
   $ curl -o azureclient.rpm https://rhui-1.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/microsoft-azure-rhel6/Packages/r/rhui-azure-rhel6-2.2-97.noarch.rpm
    $ sudo rpm -U azureclient.rpm
    $ sudo yum clean all
    $ sudo yum repolist all
```

RHEL 7:

```
    $ curl -o azureclient.rpm https://rhui-1.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/microsoft-azure-rhel7/Packages/r/rhui-azure-rhel7-2.2-97.noarch.rpm
    $ sudo rpm -U azureclient.rpm
    $ sudo yum clean all
    $ sudo yum repolist all
```

Root Cause: The certificate for the RHUI client is no longer valid and needs to be updated.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't download rhui-azure-rhel7-2.2-74.noarch.rpm using wget, you can use a manual update procedure. 
Worked for me.

This one:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/update-infrastructure-redhat#manual-update-procedure-to-use-the-azure-rhui-servers

Shortly, it is:

```
# Download key
curl -o RPM-GPG-KEY-microsoft-azure-release https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/D/9/9d945f05-541d-494f-9977-289b3ce8e774/microsoft-sign-public.asc

# Validate it
# keyid must be EB3E94ADBE1229CF
# user ID must be "Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>"
gpg --list-packets --verbose < RPM-GPG-KEY-microsoft-azure-release

# Install it
sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 RPM-GPG-KEY-microsoft-azure-release /etc/pki/rpm-gpg
sudo rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-microsoft-azure-release
```

Then you will be able to download and install rpm of Azure client (if needed)

```
# RHEL 6
curl -o azureclient.rpm https://rhui-1.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/microsoft-azure-rhel6/Packages/r/rhui-azure-rhel6-2.2-74.noarch.rpm

# RHEL 7
curl -o azureclient.rpm https://rhui-1.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/microsoft-azure-rhel7/Packages/r/rhui-azure-rhel7-2.2-74.noarch.rpm

# Install
sudo rpm -U azureclient.rpm
```

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure with your [answer link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)
 While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -3):

Try run `sudo yum upgrade` and then you should be able to have this working

SSL expire issue on Azure RHEL 7 before can be easily brushed out by running `sudo yum upgrade` to force refreshing these certs.